# Netbeans not recognize Xdebug(waiting for connections)

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, remote-server

I can't debug my  remote server project, when I press debug button it show the waiting for connection(netbeans-xdebug) message.

Im on OS X Mavericks

This is my actual config. 
in Options/PHP/Debugging on Netbeans:

```
Debugger port: 9000
Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
and Stop at First Line: unchecked
```

in my php.ini file this lines:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1  
xdebug.remote_handler=‘dbgp’
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
```

Xdebug its correctly installed. 
in terminal: 
    php -v

```
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

What it's wrong? why the debug doesnt work?

Comment: First I would ensure that the firewall doesn't block that connection.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but my firewall is Off

Comment: Great. So try to start the debugging in NetBeans and then manually open your website in a browser.

Comment: got the same waiting for connection problem, I can do any GET and it ignore the breakpoints

Comment: Maybe you could try [Xdebug helper extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) if it helps. There are also similar extensions for other browsers.

Comment: Also check "Run Configuration" under the project properties in NetBeans.

Comment: I checked my run configuration and i think the're ok. I downloaded Xdebug helper extension for safari but it seems doesnt work, i dont know how to make it work